# Deepcopy specific attributes

Tags: python, oop, copy

Is there a way to override the `__copy__` method for a class in a way such that *some* attributes are only copied *as a reference* and other attributes are actually *copied*?

To clarify what I mean, here's my guess on how this could be done. Consider the class `Spam`:

```
class Spam:
    def __init__(self, val=0, val2=0):
        self.eggs = []
        self.foo = []
        self.val = val
        self.val2 = val2
```

Suppose we wanted to make sure that, upon calling `copy.copy` (i.e. a shallow copy) on a `Spam` object, its `eggs` attribute was *deep-copied* into the new object (so that mutations to the original object's attribute don't alter the copy's `eggs` attribute). "Why don't you just `deepcopy` the whole object then?"—because, unlike `eggs`, we want the `foo` attribute to be copied as a *reference* (so that changes to it are visible to all copies).

Then, would the following be a valid approach?

```
    to_be_copied = ['eggs']  # States which attributes are to be copied

    def __copy__(self):
        copy_ = Spam()

        for attr in self.__dict__:
            if attr in Spam.to_be_copied:
                # Make an actual copy of the attribute
                copy_.__dict__[attr] = copy.copy(self.__dict__[attr])  
            else:
                # Copy reference
                copy_.__dict__[attr] = self.__dict__[attr]

        return copy_
```

Comment: it would be if you _returned_ `copy_` in the end, and making a `set` of `to_be_copied` would make operation faster when there's a lot of attributes.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre thank you for pointing that out! The missing `return` statement was a slip-up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks valid, but making a `set` of `to_be_copied` would make operation faster when there's a lot of attributes.

Also, shorten with a ternary expression + list comprehension like below

```
to_be_copied = {'eggs'}  # States which attributes are to be copied

def __copy__(self):
    copy_ = Spam()
    copy_.__dict__ = {attr:copy.copy(self.__dict__[attr]) if attr in Spam.to_be_copied else self.__dict__[attr] for attr in self.__dict__}
    return copy_
```

The downside of overriding `__copy__` dunder method is that it doesn't comply to the principle of least surprise: users of `copy.copy` expect a shallow copy when they deal with known objects like `list`, you're providing a custom copy.

Maybe it would be better to define a `def copy(self):` function instead (properly documented)